# Metamask integration with web3.py

Tags: metamask, python, web3.py

I've used metamask with web3.js multiple times before, with no issue. It's simple to integrate it, like discussed here: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/blob/master/docs/providers.rst

How does one do this for web3.py?

Comment: [eth-account](https://github.com/ethereum/eth-account) might be an option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MetaMask is a browser extension, so it's only available from code running in the browser. So to use it from web3.py, you'd first have to find a way to run Python code in the browser. This is perhaps technically possible but definitely not worth the trouble.

If you're writing code in the browser, stick with JavaScript (and therefore web3.js).