# how to connect wallet to dapp using python

Tags: web3.py

I'm looking for example code to connect a wallet to the dapp website, but I can't find it.

I want to use Metamask to implement the process of pressing “connect wallet” on a dapp and signing with python code.

I need help.

Comment: Hi! There are a few places on the site questions like this have been asked before, you may want to look at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/44017/27270